# What is the use of '~' symbol in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can anyone explain what is the use of '~' symbol in CSS?

I have an example where

```
.myclass label: hover ~ label: before {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

I didn't get the usage of ~ symbol here. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

This selector is called [General Siblings Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

See [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent.

From CSS [Specifications](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators):

> The **following-sibling combinator** is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~) character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the document tree and the element represented by the first sequence precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the second one.

**Example Demo**

```css
p ~ span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>This is not red.</span>
<p>Here is a paragraph.</p>
<code>Here is some code.</code>
<span>And here is a span.</span>
```

Comment: Hi Tushar, will it apply to all the siblings or only one sibling?

Comment: @Vijay It'll be applied to all the matched elements following

Comment: @Vijay Welcome! Kindly accept the answer, if this has helped you

Answer (score 1):

I think this will make you clear

`element1~element2`

```
p ~ ul  Selects every <ul> element that are preceded by a <p> element
```